# How can I read a password from the command line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am running Ruby and MySQL on a Windows box.

I have some Ruby code that needs to connect to a MySQL database a perform a select. To connect to the database I need to provide the password among other things.

The Ruby code can display a prompt requesting the password, the user types in the password and hits the Enter key. What I need is for the password, as it is typed, to be displayed as a line of asterisks.

How can I get Ruby to display the typed password as a line of asterisks in the 'dos box'?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To answer my own question, and for the benefit of anyone else who would like to know, there is a Ruby gem called [HighLine](http://rubydoc.info/gems/highline/frames) that you need.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

def get_password(prompt="Enter Password")
   ask(prompt) {|q| q.echo = false}
end

thePassword = get_password()
```

Comment: highline wouldn't work for me, it still echoed the password. I think it had something to do with termios not being installed, but it still didn't work after installing ruby-termios. I used ruby-password instead.

Answer (score 24):

Poor man's solution:

```
system "stty -echo"
# read password
system "stty echo"
```

Or using http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-password/

> The target audience for this library is system administrators who need to write Ruby programs that prompt for, generate, verify and encrypt passwords.

**Edit:** Whoops I failed to notice that you need this for Windows :(

Comment: I tried this in combination with readline and I could still see the password

Comment: password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp; #   <-- this should work too (probably not for windows)

Answer (score 12):

According to the Highline doc, this seems to work. Not sure if it will work on Windows.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

username = ask("Enter your username:  ") { |q| q.echo = true }
password = ask("Enter your password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
```

Here's the output on the console:

```
$ ruby highline.rb 
Enter your username:  doug
Enter your password:  ******
```

Comment: If you are running the script with the `ruby` command, you don't need the `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby`, if you were running the script directly, with `./highline.rb`, you would.

Comment: Let me add that usually #!/usr/bin/env ruby is better as a first line as it finds the ruby installation regardless of where it is.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from Ruby 2.3 you can use the `IO#getpass` method as such:

```
require 'io/console' 

STDIN.getpass("Password: ")
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getpass

The above is copied from a deleted answer by [Zoran Majstorovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3452582/zoran-majstorovic).

Comment: Nice. And as the documentation states, "You must require 'io/console' to use this method."

Comment: Thanks, simplest and most elegant solution for this :)

Answer (score 4):

The following works (lobin.rb) in ruby not jruby

```
require 'highline/import'

$userid = ask("Enter your username:  ") { |q| q.echo = true }
$passwd = ask("Enter your password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
```

Output from console:

```
E:\Tools>ruby login.rb
Enter your username:  username
Enter your password:  ********
```

Howerver if I run in jruby it fails and gives no opportunity to enter your password.

```
E:\Tools>jruby login.rb
Enter your username:  username
Enter your password:
```

Answer (score 0):

The fancy_gets gem has a password thing that works fine with jruby:

https://github.com/lorint/fancy_gets

Code ends up like:

```
require 'fancy_gets'
include FancyGets

puts "Password:"
pwd = gets_password
# ...
```