# Why cannot use instance method noecho of class IO?

Tags: ruby, passwords

```
print "Enter your password: "
pass = STDIN.noecho(&:gets)
puts "Your password is #{pass}!"
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Enter your password: input.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `noecho' for #<IO:<STDIN>> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: There is no such method for STDIN, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699134/ruby-stdin-gets-without-showing-chars-on-screen) to see how to accept password

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133719/how-can-i-read-a-password

Comment: Thanks a lot, with highline it is okey!

Answer (score 10):

At first

```
require 'io/console'
```

later Ruby 1.9.3